# HP 845C not printing in normal grayscale mode

Tags: printing, hp

My HP 845C printer is not printing in normal grayscale mode (Ubuntu 18.04). Printer is OK. in draft grayscale mode, but when switching to normal grayscale mode printing is not performed. Message in CUPS: stopped "Filter failed".

More info from /var/log/cups/$ error_log file:
prnt/hpcups/Pcl3Gui.cpp 75: Requested resolution not supported with requested printmodeprnt/hpcups/HPCupsFilter.cpp 486: m_Job initiali$
D [03/Jan/2021:00:33:08 +0100] [Job 31] PID 24718 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/hpcups) stopped with status 1.

I have HPLIP installed. Also hp-check -t ran and I have installed all missing librares - no errors now from hp-check.

I have found this thread:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/hplip/+bug/782706
reported by Alexander Kandaurov and it seems he has attached even solution - patch with code for this issue, but I don't know what do to next to implement solution, as I am rather noob in Ubuntu, but like it. Could You please help me with implementing resolution changes at least for normal gray scale mode?

Thanks in advance
Regards
Tomasz

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I am happy that you signed your problem and posted the solution as an answer. Please don't put SOLVED in the question title. After the required wait time click on the gray check mark ✔️ and turn it green ✅. This will indicate you have accepted your answer as the correct answer to the question and help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are available at least 3 drivers for this printer in CUPS (http://127.0.0.1:631/ or http://localhost:631). Don't worry to 'Modify Printer' and change driver. Input user and password, then do not change nothing on 1st (connection) and 2nd screen - just click continue and on 3rd screen select driver. By default was HP Deskjet 845C hpcups 3.17.10 (en). I have tried

HP Deskjet 845c CUPS+Gutenprint v5.2.13 (en)

and all is working fine now. I can choose different options for printing and everything is working OK. Even printing quality of drawings/schematics from pdf is good now - not blurred as before. Before I was forced to paste print screens/diagrams to KolourPaint and print as png. Sorry guys if someone was already busy with this thread. Solved. Regards.

Comment: I have the same problem with HP 840C printer.  Your solution worked with the following corrections: 
In my case in Ubuntu 22.04 the driver I use is `HP DeskJet 840C - CUPS+Gutenprint v5.3.3 (color)` .   
I also had to change options in default printer settings  `Resolution:` from `Automatic` to `600x300 DPI`  (tested with `Color Model: Grayscale`).